# JVM error on trying to launch Astana 3

Tags: java, aptana3

Getting the following error when trying to launch Aptana 3 on my MacBook Pro.  Running El Capitan (OS X 10.11) beta with 16 GB ram.  Java is in place and working.

No issues on another MacBook Pro running Yosemite.

Here is the text of the Alert from Astana:

> The JVM shared library:
>
> ```
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
> ```
>
> Does not contain the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: I improved the formatting. Please mention the error you are referring to and also mention the version of the Mac OS in with you are getting the error.

Comment: Ram, I'm running OS X 10.11.  The Error was an alert that popped up from Astana as I try to launch it.  The text of the alert is in the post.

Comment: Please edit the question and update it to mention it was an alert and the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in another thread:

[Aptana studio 3 hang & won't start up in El Capitan beta 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318544/aptana-studio-3-hang-wont-start-up-in-el-capitan-beta-3)

Apparently, El Capitan Beta 3 has a problem with some Java based applications, including those based on Eclipse.