# Aptana studio 3 hang & won't start up in El Capitan beta 3

Tags: java, aptana3, osx-elcapitan

i have installed JavaForOSX.pkg from Apple's official Java Package and successfully , up and running with Aptana sutido 3 standalone version for  El Capitan beta2 , no problem at all . I used the instructions by p0wer0n from http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-java-6-for-10-11.1890762/page-2

After beta 3 upgraded , Aptana studio 3 hand and won't start up at all .

I reinstalled JavaForOSX.pkg  and Aptana studio 3 , still not working .

Did anybody have this issues and knew any solution to it ?

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly just by updating your Java. I found the solution on this link: http://lab.dejaworks.com/after-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade-necessary-java-update/

and here is the java for osx download link: https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/javaforosx.dmg

I'm using El Captian release version

Comment: Not so much, no.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue with java interfaces on Beta 3 of El Capitan.

you can have more info in [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8776). But looks like we will need to waiting for the Beta 4 :(

Edit: You can downgrade to DP 1 and then upgrade to DP 2. To downgrade you can use your previous created disk or download for purchase tab on App Store.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info , have to wait :(

Comment: Hey theres a update, you can go back to the DP1 in your purchase tab on App Store (will install like an update). This will make aptana works again :)

Comment: great !!! just found my previous download one ! downgraded from dp3 to dp1 . thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by installing update 2:

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/07/10/031-25506/wy6k3cd22jejq1j83kmahud7zwbaxid2z6/OSXUpd10.11.pkg

Found this solution here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8776

Update: Here is the post that led to the solution

dsarch
Jul 17, 2015 8:13 AM
(in response to littleodie914)
Hello,

For anyone that have this problem, you just need to download this:

... (the link that I provided above) ...

Install and reboot.

Then you will be back to the developer preview 2 that does not have the issue that makes java apps hang and other apps, like Axure.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the contents of those webpages may be updated or disappear, could you post the relevant information directly in your answer? Thanks.